# XPS 13 9360 install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 or erase Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot

XPS 13 9360

Should I install Ubuntu next to Windows 10 or erase Windows 10 and only install Ubuntu?

Comment: If you are asking the question probably better to keep Windows. Only those who have used Linux for a while and know what works and what only partially works but is acceptable and do not want Windows software then erase Windows. We get many users wanting to reinstall Windows as one game or application they must have is only available in Windows. It took me 5  years to totally wean myself off Windows. And then I had to add a Windows system to watch DRM protected streaming TV  shows. :(

Comment: @oldfred:  :D :D :D I keep windows to upgrade my BIOS as there is no EFI version yet and to reprogram my keyboard lights.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want. Totally erasing Windows 10 means that you'll have to reinstall, update, configure, and install all your old windows apps again. This can take hours, so I recommend keeping a backup Windows image.

A side by side dual boot of Ubuntu and Windows on the same machine is usually what most users go for. Though you'll likely encounter minor issues, such as with the system time on Windows 10 if you do this.